# Google Play Store - Find out why a device is incompatible

Tags: android, google-play

I published an android app in google playstore. Some clients complain about not being able to download the app as the play stores says it is "not compatible".

In google developer console, I can only see THAT a device is not supported. I want to know WHY a device is incompatible but that information is hidden from me.

Google has to have this information to determine compatibility, why is there no way to show this information to developers? Or am I wrong?

We'd really appreciate that feature, it is vital I think.

One device that fails, is for example: medion lifetab e10315 
http://www.amazon.de/Medion-LIFETAB-Tablet-PC-Android-schwarz/dp/B00HA4M91W

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.example.changed.android2"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="xxx" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- Only this application can receive the messages and registration result -->
    <permission
        android:name="de.example.changed.android2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="de.example.changed.android2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <!-- Required permission to check licensing. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="de.example.changed.android2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="de.example.changed.android2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--in app paying-->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="false" />

    <!-- suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
    <instrumentation
        android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
        android:label="Tests for xxx"
        android:targetPackage="de.example.changed.android2" />

    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".xxxApp"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.xxx" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".services.C2DMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="de.example.changed.android" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="de.example.changed.android" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".services.NetworkChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".services.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="9999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.RegistrationActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MapActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.GroupsEdit"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.GroupsList" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.example.changed.android2.ui.GroupsList" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.GroupsList"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.AlertListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.example.changed.android2.ui.AlertListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AlertListActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.HelpActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AlertDetailActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.AlertListActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.example.changed.android2.ui.AlertListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.AlertPopupActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
            android:noHistory="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".services.helper.test.EncryptionTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_encryption_test" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".services.helper.test.EncryptionClientTest"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_encryption_client_test" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.BlockedAlertListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blocked_alert_list" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.example.changed.android2.ui.AlertListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.StartActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:noHistory="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.FeedbackCustomTextActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged" />

        <!-- Widgets -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".ui.Widget"
            android:label="@string/widget_title" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="de.example.changed.android2.ui.Widget.WIDGET_CLICK" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="de.example.changed.android2.ui.Widget.WIDGET_UPDATE_UI" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_provider" />
        </receiver>

        <!-- Services -->


        <!-- Provider -->
        <provider
            android:name=".provider.FilterProvider"
            android:authorities="de.example.changed" >
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".ui.FeedbackOverviewActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ProfileListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_list"
            android:parentActivityName=".ui.GroupsList" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="de.example.changed.android2.ui.GroupsList" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.ProfileEditActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_edit" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".billing.BillingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_billing" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: If you are using a permission in the app, some device may not be compatible with it

Answer (score 0):

remove android:targetSdkVersion="18"